# How to not assign an id when id is a fk with a custom id generator in ef

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

I have a project where I'm using EF5, I made a custom Guid Generator and I have an override of the SaveChanges method to assign the ids of my entities.

Everything is working fine except in one case: when the ID of one entity is a FK to another ID of another entity.

A little bit of code to explain the problem:

**I have two entities I cannot change:**

```
public class FixedEntityA
{
    public Guid Id { get; set;}
    public string SomeText { get; set; }
}

public class FixedEntityB
{
    public Guid Id { get; set;}
    public int OneInt { get; set; }
}
```

**In my project I have an entity defined like this:**

```
public class ComposedEntity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set;}
    public FixedEntityA FixedA { get; set; }
    public FixedEntityB FixedB { get; set; }
    public double OneDouble { get; set; }
}
```

**The relationships are:**

ComposedEntity may have 0 or 1 FixedEntityA

ComposedEntity may have 0 or 1 FixedEntityB

**The constraints on the id are:**

The Id of FixedEntityA is a FK pointing to the Id of ComposedEntity

The Id of FixedEntityB is a FK pointing to the Id of ComposedEntity

**The mapping class are:**

```
public ComposedEntity(): EntityTypeConfiguration<ComposedEntity>
{
    HasOptional(fea => fea.FixedA).WithRequired();
    HasOptional(feb => feb.FixedB).WithRequired();
}
```

**Here is my SaveChanges override:**

```
foreach (var entry in ChangeTracker.Entries<IEntity>().Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Added))
{
   Type t = entry.Entity.GetType();

   List<DatabaseGeneratedAttribute> info = t.GetProperty("Id")
                                            .GetCustomAttributes(typeof (DatabaseGeneratedAttribute), true)
                                            .Cast<DatabaseGeneratedAttribute>().ToList();

   if (!info.Any() || info.Single().DatabaseGeneratedOption != DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)
   {
       if (entry.Entity.Id == Guid.Empty)
            entry.Entity.Id = (Guid) _idGenerator.Generate();
   }
}
return base.SaveChanges();
```

This code works fine everywhere for all kind of relationships except in this case, I am missing a test to make sure I'am not setting an id on id that are foreign keys, and I have no clue on how to check if an Id is a FK...

Here is a sample object where this code fails:

```
var fea = new FixedEntityA();
var feb = new FixedEntityB();
var composedEntity = new ComposedEntity();

composedEntity.FixedA = fea;
composedEntity.FixedB = feb;
```

If you insert the whole graph, all three objects are marked as Added and all Ids are default.

The problem is, with the current SaveChanges method, I will go through all object with the Added state in the change tracker and I will assign an Id to all entity with a default Guid and break my FK constraints.

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: If the Id is an FK isn't `entry.Entity.Id != Guid.Empty` in which case  you don't assign a generated Id? I don't understand the problem very well. For me an example which shows when your code causes errors (and which errors) would help.

Comment: @Slauma, I updated the message, Id is still empty in FixedEntityA & B because DynamicProxy are disabled

Comment: I tried calling DetectChanges everytime I set an Id on ComposedEntity but it doesn't update the Id on FixedA and FixedB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some code that will get the FK properties for a given type (it's horrible I know). Should be simple enough to plug this into your code.

```
var typeName = "Category";

var fkProperties = ((IObjectContextAdapter)db)
    .ObjectContext
    .MetadataWorkspace
    .GetItems<AssociationType>(DataSpace.CSpace)
    .Where(a => a.IsForeignKey)
    .Select(a => a.ReferentialConstraints.Single())
    .Where(c => c.FromRole.GetEntityType().Name == typeName)
    .SelectMany(c => c.FromProperties)
    .Select(p => p.Name);
```

Comment: Thanks Rowan, will have a look at it!